# install ghcjs from stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghcjs

I have GHC installed through stack ( so that `stack ghc -- --version` shows GHC-7.10.3 )

```
$ stack install ghcjs

Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-5.2 from implicit global project's config file: /home/john/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
The following target packages were not found: ghcjs
```

Some resources suggest **`ghcjs`** is somewhat experimental (though in the further stages).

---

Looking at http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/ghcjs/ I thought maybe I could find `stack.yaml` and change it.

> To use GHCJS with stack >= 0.1.8, place a GHCJS version in the compiler field of stack.yaml ... then `stack setup`

```
$ cat ~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
# This is the implicit global project's config file, which is only used when
# 'stack' is run outside of a real project.  Settings here do _not_ act as
# defaults for all projects.  To change stack's default settings, edit
# '/home/john/.stack/config.yaml' instead.
#
# For more information about stack's configuration, see
# http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration.html
#
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
packages: []
extra-deps: []
resolver: lts-5.2
```

We are told to look at `config.yaml` which looks equally blank.  Is this even right, am I going up a dead end?

```
$ cat ~/.stack/config.yaml
# This file contains default non-project-specific settings for 'stack', used
# in all projects.  For more information about stack's configuration, see
# http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration.html
#
{}
```

I just want to install **`ghcjs`** with stack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at this page: http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/ghcjs/

I would try:

1. Start a new stack project, e.g. `stack new js-test`
2. Modify the stack.yaml file by adding this stanza (taken from the above mentioned link):

   ```
   compiler: ghcjs-0.2.0.20160414_ghc-7.10.3
   compiler-check: match-exact
   setup-info:
     ghcjs:
       source:
         ghcjs-0.2.0.20160414_ghc-7.10.3:
           url: https://s3.amazonaws.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-0.2.0.20160414_ghc-7.10.3.tar.gz
           sha1: 6d6f307503be9e94e0c96ef1308c7cf224d06be3
   ```
3. Change the `resolver:` to lts-5.12 - this matches the above stanza.
4. Run `stack setup` to get the compiler installed.

Step 4 will take a while.

Comment: I can't put a check-mark cuz it's still installing :-)

Comment: My `stack setup` just finished so hang in there!

Comment: Docs returns 404 currently